# Returning iterations with React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loops, return, jsx

I've been using React not too long, but I keep running into this issue while trying to avoid it every time.

Upon iterating through my forloop, it gives me two different iterations, as expected.

Output:

`{name: "Sensor 1", type: "Airsensor"}`

`{name: "Sensor 2", type: "Watersensor"}`

However, my code seems to be only using the second iteration.

Output on screen:

`{name: "Sensor 2", type: "Watersensor"}`

`{name: "Sensor 2", type: "Watersensor"}`

The code in question is:

```
export default function SensorCards() {
  let allCards = [
    {name: 'Sensor 1', type: 'Airsensor'},
    {name: 'Sensor 2', type: 'Watersensor'},
  ];

  for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
    var cardsOnScreen = allCards.map(function (card) {
      return <Card name={allCards[i].name} type={allCards[i].type} />;
    });
  }
  return cardsOnScreen;
}
```

I keep trying to change the return to something else, because I think my issue lays there, however I can't seem to find an alternative for my situation. My return keeps only returning the last object x times in objects.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
    var cardsOnScreen = allCards.map(function (card) {
      return <Card name={allCards[i].name} type={allCards[i].type} />;
    });
  }
  return cardsOnScreen;
```

with this:

```
    return allCards.map((card) => (
      <Card key={card.name} name={card.name} type={card.type} />
    ));
```

The problem in your code are:

1. You are looping twice, you don't need to.
2. You are resetting `cardOnScreen` in the inner loop
3. You are not setting `key` when looping

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
export default function SensorCards() {
  let allCards = [
    {name: 'Sensor 1', type: 'Airsensor'},
    {name: 'Sensor 2', type: 'Watersensor'},
  ];
  return (
     <>
       { allCards.map((card) => (
      <Card key={card.name} name={card.name} type={card.type} />
       ))}
     </>
  )
}
```